# How can I send email over IPv6 properly?

Tags: ios, delphi, ipv6

I am developing an email sending function in my iOS and Android apps.

It is a function to send an email via Gmail using OpenSSL.

I am using Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo, with Indy 10.

I submitted my iOS app to iTunes Connect, but they rejected my app because this function does not work in IPv6.

They said

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 11.4.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

They also send me a screenshot of the error saying

> An error occurred when resolving address smtp.gmail.com: (8)

How can I fix this error to work with IPv6 properly?  My code is below:

```
Procedure MailSend; 
Var
  Connected: Boolean; 
Begin 
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil); 
  try 
    IdSMTP.Host     := 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
    IdSMTP.Port     := 587; 
    IdSMTP.Username := 'xxxx@gmail.com'; // UserName 
    IdSMTP.Password := 'xxxx';       // Password 
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create; 

    try 
      SSL.Host := IdSMTP.Host; 
      SSL.Port := IdSMTP.Port; 
      SSL.Destination := SSL.Host + ':' + IntToStr(SSL.Port); 
      IdSMTP.IOHandler := SSL; 
      IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS; 

      IdSMTP.Socket.IPVersion := Id_IPv6; 
      try 
        IdSMTP.Connect; 
        Connected := True; 
      except 
        Connected := False; 
      end; 

      If Connected = False then 
      Begin 
        IdSMTP.Socket.IPVersion := Id_IPv4; 
        IdSMTP.Connect; 
      End; 

      Msg := TIdMessage.Create(IdSMTP); 
      try 
        Msg.OnInitializeISO           := IdMessage_InitializeISO; 
        Msg.ContentType               := 'text/plain'; 
        Msg.CharSet                   := 'UTF-8'; 
        Msg.ContentTransferEncoding   := 'BASE64'; // BASE64 (7bit) 
        //Msg.ContentTransferEncoding   := '8bit';   // RAW(8bit) 
        Msg.From.Name                 := SsNoSt; 
        Msg.From.Address              := 'xxxx@gmail.com'; 
        Msg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'xxxx@gmail.com'; 
        Msg.Subject                   := SsNoSt; 
        Msg.Body.Text                 := 'Unicode String (body)'; 
        IdSMTP.Send(Msg); 
      finally 
        Msg.Free; 
      end; 
      IdSMTP.Disconnect; 
    finally 
      SSL.Free; 
    end; 
  finally 
    IdSMTP.Free; 
  End; 
End;
```

Comment: You are asking two completely separate and unrelated questions.  StackOverflow guidelines ask for one question per post. So please, delete the second question about opening urls and re-post it separately, it doesn't belong with the first question about connecting to SMTP over IPv6.

Comment: In the 2nd question, the error message is telling you that a `nil` pointer is being accessed, so you need to hunt that down. But there is no reason at all to perform a manual TCP check before opening a url. You are spawning an external app to open the url, so let that app handle connectivity errors as it needs.  Especially since you proceed to open the url anyway if both `Connect()` calls fail.  So just get rid of `TIdTCPClient` from your procedure altogether, it doesn't belong there.  That is probably where your `nil` pointer is coming from.

Comment: @Remy Thank you very much for teaching me guideline of StackOverFlow. First of all, I follow your indication to separate second question and repost it.

Comment: there is no reason to link to the other question from the body of this question, since it has nothing to do with this question.  I have removed it.  It should have been posted in a comment instead, if at all.  For anyone who is interested, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51643713/.

Answer (score 5):

I see a few problems with your SMTP code:

- you need to set the `IdSMTP.IPVersion` property instead of the `IdSMTP.Socket.IPVersion` property.  The default value of the `IPVersion` property is `Id_IPv4` ([bug](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/222) - it is not respecting the `ID_DEFAULT_IP_VERSION` constant in the `IdGlobal` unit).  `Connect()` overwrites the `Socket.IPVersion` property value with the `IPVersion` property value, so you are actually attempting to connect using `Id_IPv4` twice, which will fail on an IPv6-only network (which Apple requires apps to support).
- you are not catching any errors from the 2nd `Connect()`.  That is likely the error that Apple is ultimately seeing.
- you should not be setting the `SSL.Host`, `SSL.Port`, and `SSL.Destination` properties manually.  Let `Connect()` handle that for you.

Try this instead:

```
// this accessor class is needed because TIdSMTP derives from TIdTCPClientCustom
// instead of TIdTCPClient.  The IPVersion property is protected in
// TIdTCPClientCustom and not published by TIdSMTP or its ancestors.
//
// See https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/184 ...
//
type
  TIdSMTPAccess = class(TIdSMTP)
  end;

procedure MailSend; 
var
  IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  Msg: TIdMessage;
begin 
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdSMTP);
    IdSMTP.IOHandler := SSL;

    IdSMTP.Host     := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Port     := 587;
    IdSMTP.Username := 'xxxx@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Password := 'xxxx';
    IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS; 

    TIdSMTPAccess(IdSMTP).IPVersion := Id_IPv6; 
    try 
      IdSMTP.Connect; 
    except 
      TIdSMTPAccess(IdSMTP).IPVersion := Id_IPv4; 
      try
        IdSMTP.Connect; 
      except
        // unable to connect!
        Exit;
      end;
    end; 

    try
      Msg := TIdMessage.Create(nil); 
      try 
        Msg.OnInitializeISO           := IdMessage_InitializeISO; 
        Msg.ContentType               := 'text/plain'; 
        Msg.CharSet                   := 'UTF-8'; 
        Msg.ContentTransferEncoding   := 'BASE64'; // BASE64 (7bit) 
        //Msg.ContentTransferEncoding   := '8bit';   // RAW(8bit) 
        Msg.From.Name                 := SsNoSt; 
        Msg.From.Address              := 'xxxx@gmail.com'; 
        Msg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'xxxx@gmail.com'; 
        Msg.Subject                   := SsNoSt; 
        Msg.Body.Text                 := 'Unicode String (body)'; 

        IdSMTP.Send(Msg); 
      finally 
        Msg.Free; 
      end; 
    finally
      IdSMTP.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally 
    IdSMTP.Free; 
  end; 
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
type
  TIdSMTPAccess = class(TIdSMTP)
  end;

procedure MailSend; 
var
  IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  Msg: TIdMessage;
  Connected: Boolean;
begin 
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdSMTP);
    IdSMTP.IOHandler := SSL;

    IdSMTP.Host     := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Port     := 587;
    IdSMTP.Username := 'xxxx@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Password := 'xxxx';
    IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS; 

    Connected := False;

    if GStack.SupportsIPv6 then
    begin
      TIdSMTPAccess(IdSMTP).IPVersion := Id_IPv6; 
      try 
        IdSMTP.Connect; 
        Connected := True;
      except 
      end; 
    end;

    if (not Connected) and GStack.SupportsIPv4 then
    begin
      TIdSMTPAccess(IdSMTP).IPVersion := Id_IPv4; 
      try 
        IdSMTP.Connect; 
        Connected := True;
      except 
      end; 
    end;

    if not Connected then
    begin
      // unable to connect!
      Exit;
    end; 

    try
      Msg := TIdMessage.Create(nil); 
      try 
        Msg.OnInitializeISO           := IdMessage_InitializeISO; 
        Msg.ContentType               := 'text/plain'; 
        Msg.CharSet                   := 'UTF-8'; 
        Msg.ContentTransferEncoding   := 'BASE64'; // BASE64 (7bit) 
        //Msg.ContentTransferEncoding   := '8bit';   // RAW(8bit) 
        Msg.From.Name                 := SsNoSt; 
        Msg.From.Address              := 'xxxx@gmail.com'; 
        Msg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'xxxx@gmail.com'; 
        Msg.Subject                   := SsNoSt; 
        Msg.Body.Text                 := 'Unicode String (body)'; 

        IdSMTP.Send(Msg); 
      finally 
        Msg.Free; 
      end; 
    finally
      IdSMTP.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally 
    IdSMTP.Free; 
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your posting codes. However, I have error messages for your first one, saying '[DCC error] URegistration.pas (142): E2362 Can not access protected symbol TIdTCPClientCustom.IPVersion', at "    IdSMTP.IPVersion := Id_IPv6;". In the structure part of Delphi said ’IdSMTP does not include a member named IPVersion’. It Is also error at "IdSMTP.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;". How can I fix them?

Comment: @miro My bad, I forgot that is a known issue in Indy. I updated my answer

Comment: I really appreciate your hard work. I modified my code following what you had written here. It works fine in my iPhone 6s Plus. I submitted my app to iTunes Connect for its reviewing. Now I wait the results. I will inform how it goes here. I hope it also goes fine.

Comment: I really thank you for your hard work. Your code works fine and was accepted by iTunes Connect. However, Apple demands another issue. I will try to hit it. I may ask some help for you. In that case, please help me again.